# Vue How to destroy already created and mounted tooltip component to the #app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create a custom Vue tooltip directive that creates a component and render/mounts it to the application's root element.

Currently, it is mounting the `tooltip` component on `mouseenter` as it should, but not destroying it on `mouseleave`.

Later, I'll get the element ClientRect which the directive is bound to it and apply styles to position the tooltip.

Here is my directive code:

```
import Vue from 'Vue';
import tooltip from '../../views/components/tooltip/tooltip.vue';

export default {
    bind() {},
    inserted(el) {
        let component;
        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            const Tooltip = Vue.extend(tooltip);
            component = new Tooltip().$mount();
            document.getElementById('app').appendChild(component.$el);
        });
        el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            component.$destroy();
        });
    },
    update() {},
    componentUpdated() {},
    unbind() {},
};
```

How can I properly destroy the component on `mouseleave`?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do this with `v-if`, and just update a data item on mouseenter and mouseleave?

Comment: The reason is that I don't want to pollute the dom with the same tooltip element for each time i use the directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a reference to the component when you create it within the `inserted` hook, and call [`$destroy`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-destroy) on it when you need to destroy it. Since you are manually mounting the component, you'll need to manually remove the HTML element as well:

```
inserted(el) {
  let component;
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    let Tooltip = Vue.extend(tooltip);
    component = new ToolTip().$mount();
    document.getElementById('app').appendChild(component.$el);
  });
  el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    document.getElementById('app').removeChild(component.$el);
    component.$destroy();
  });
},
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0sszwocb/)

Comment: Store the reference in the inserted hook.

Comment: this approach don't give any errors but the tooltip component does not get destroyed

Comment: although it triggers the beforeDestroy and destroyed hooks inside `tooltip` component

Comment: lol ok sorry for thinking I could do this from memory. You need to also manually remove the html element. See my edit